# Best level grinding spot?

Tags: disgaea-5

Which Netherworld level has enemies on a 3x3 formation, cross shaped, or at least has enemies positioned in a way that a few Magic attacks can kill them off? Preferably with a Geo Symbol that increases EXP gain. I'm still on chapter 9, so no Post-Game stuffs.

Like something similar to the first stage of Spirit Interment, where the 3 Zombies and 2 Imps are easily decimated be a single Zielregen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet for leveling up is by using the Martial Training missions. You unlock your first trial at chapter 8. In order to unlock the Martial training missions you need to pass a bill in the senate to unlock the mission.

Once you unlock the mission play the trial on the lowest difficulty and clear the mission for the first time. After you complete it once the trial changes and spawns three enemies on an +100% exp geo-panel. You can use tower skills to level up a bunch of characters at the same time and make your job of killing enemies even easier. Once you start gaining fewer levels from killing the enemies use the cheat shop and up the difficulty of the enemies to get even more EXP. Do note that by setting Martial Training's difficulty to 1 star you get level 99 enemies which give even more EXP for defeating them.

If your party isn't up to snuff to fight level 99+ enemies farm level 2-1 to get a tanky character to around 50-80 by using tower skills to kill enemies faster. After that you can farm 4-2 with 16 stars to get level 99 enemies that you can kill using tower skills. Once you get a sufficiently tough tank switch to martial training and use the tank as the base for your towers. You should be able to rack up a bunch of levels with each enemy killed.

Hope this helps, and happy grinding!

Comment: In the end, the leveling isn't even the hardest part of the grind. With the right setup, clearing the final Martial training map gets you from 1 to 9999 in a single clear.

Comment: The hardest part of the grind is leveling up amazing gear for your OP god killing machines to use.

Comment: actually the hardest (longest) part is going through that damn Chara World minigame. I had to periodically change the music up to retain my sanity. The item world was at least *fun*.